# Can we minimise the risk of using xp_cmdshell?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, security, xp-cmdshell

Using `xp_cmdshell` can be quite helpful and sometimes possibly the only answer to some scenarios. I've read some posts on the internet that enabling `xp_cmdshell` might jeopardize the security of the database/server.

My question is that, is there anything we can do to reduce the risk? For example can we set some restrictions/applying users role, etc providing safeguards to mitigate the risk?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not with you on the following: "possibly the only answer to some scenarios". If you share your scenarios, you might get solutions not involving xp_cmdshell. We never use it in our systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you could not grant execute on it explicitly to end users (deny it even), and only enable it in stored procedures that use EXECUTE AS with some login that *does* have execute permissions. Then grant execute on only that stored procedure to the user that needs to run the command.

First, make sure `xp_cmdshell` is enabled for the instance:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
```

Now depending on operating system and SQL Server service account, you may need to set up a proxy account (and to do this, thanks to UAC, [you may need elevation and launch SSMS as an administrator](https://web.archive.org/web/20151011164643/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/psssql/archive/2009/04/07/troubleshooting-sp-xp-cmdshell-proxy-account-errors.aspx)):

```
EXEC master..sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'Domain\User', 'Password';
```

Then create a wrapper in your database that does whatever you need it to do (this is just a sample of a VERY generic wrapper that doesn't really protect you from anything; only using it to demonstrate):

```
USE yourdb;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uxp_cmdshell
  @cmd VARCHAR(2048)
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd;
END
GO
```

Now give your user or role permissions to execute the procedure:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.uxp_cmdshell TO [your_user_or_role!];
```

Now when `your_user` logs in, and tries to execute willy-nilly calls to `xp_cmdshell`:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\';
```

They will get:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

However if they pass the same command to your new procedure:

```
EXEC dbo.uxp_cmdshell 'dir c:\';
```

It will work just fine (assuming your proxy account is set up correctly and/or the SQL Server service account has adequate permissions).

This can take some work, but effectively this allows you to control *exactly* what your users can do with `xp_cmdshell`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems what I was looking for. Could you please shed some light on how to do that? Do you mean I should enable xp_cmdshell in the stored proc where it's been called before using and then disable it right after the calling statement (when I'm done with that)?

Comment: No, that tactic would not work - what if one person starts the procedure, enables xp_cmdshell, and before they call it, a different user had called the stored procedure and already hit the point where they disable it?

Comment: I see your point Aaron. You're right.

Answer (score 6):

You can also setup a proxy account using [sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190359%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to allow non-administrators to use xp_cmdshell.  This will allow you to setup a less privileged Windows account rather than xp_cmdshell always using the SQL Server service account.  This is similar to setting up proxy accounts for SQL Agent jobs.